# Extra space coming around h:inputText

Tags: css, jsf, richfaces

I am having a rich data table's column like below:

```
<h:panelGrid columns="2" width="100%"
style="text-align: center;line-height:0px;">                                                

    <h:outputText value="*"                             style="font: bold 19px;color: red;position: relative;margin:0;padding:0;"
    rendered="#{s:isNotNumber(forecastList.rasMap[mapElements])}"></h:outputText>
    <h:inputText value="#{forecastList.rasMap[mapElements]}"
    readonly="true" onfocus="captureFocus(this,this.form);"
    size="15" 
    style="#{s:contains(forecastList.rasMap[mapElements],'-') ? 'color: red;' : ''};
    text-align: right; vertical-align: middle;background-color: white;margin:0;padding:0;"
    label="For #{forecastList.currencySymbolRas} - #{mapElements},">
    <s:bigDecimalConverter decimalDigits="2" />
    </h:inputText>
                                            </h:panelGrid>
```

However i am not able to remove the space between the asterik and input text box. I want them near to each other.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `width="100%"` and (optionally) add additional attributes in `h:panelGrid`:

```
<h:panelGrid columns="2" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
```

Comment: Thanks Lukach for looking into the issue.but i had already tried it...no luck!!

Comment: Do you have more lines (or only 1 as is in question)? If more than 1 with different text, then you can remove `text-align: center` from h:panelGrid `style` attribute and use style per each column.

Comment: Additional important thing: remove `width="100%"` in `h:panelGrid`!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<h:outputText value="*" >
</h:outputText><h:inputText ... />
```

Comment: An explanation, in addition to the correct code is always appreciated (and expected, IMO).

Comment: @JonathonReinhart: Since the line-break is easy to spot, I wanted to leave the ah-ha moment for the OP :P. I will do better in the future :D